# Como atualizar requisição cURL ao chamar script

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho um sistema, que abre um site externo dentro dele, só que estou com um pequeno empecilho; toda vez que a página é acessada pela primeira vez, os dados obtidos da página externa não são atualizados, eles são salvos em cache e fica pra sempre, queria atualizar esses dados toda fez que a página chamar o script responsável por abrir a página externa.

Eu passo os dados por `Javascript` para o arquivo `PHP`, o `javascript` pega a `url` da notícia no site, e manda através do parâmetro `GET` para o `script PHP`, que realiza a abertura do site fazendo-se uso da biblioteca `cURL`.
O `Script PHP` está assim:

```
if(preg_match("#Politica#",$_GET['u'])){
    $ir = $_GET['u'];
    ob_start();
    $cot = new ExibirPolitica();
    $cot -> setUrlc($ir);
    $cot -> printCot();
    $conteudo = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $conteudo;

}
```

A Classe `ExibirPolitica();` contém apenas um cURL da seguinte forma:

```
        $header = "X-Forwarded-For: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
        $h2 = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://noticiando.com");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header,$h2));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
```

Como podem notar, tentei usar o `ob_end_clean();` e imprimir o conteúdo abaixo pra ver se vinha atualizado, também tentei o "`no-cache"` no `cURL`, também sem sucesso!

Há alguma maneira de "forçar" a atualização de um conteúdo obtido pelo `cURL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como a sua URL está formatada, mas creio que você tenha algumas variáveis nela. Então tenho duas sugestões.

```
// Em ambos casos, você precisará da variável com valor pseudo-exclusivo
// A chance do valor dessa variável se repetir é praticamente nula
// Foi dado o nome de "_u" mas pode ter qualquer outro nome
$u = '_u=' . microtime(true) . ':' . rand();
```

**Segestão 1:**
Continuar utilizando o método GET e acrescentar a variável ao fim da URL:

```
$u = ((strpos($url, '?') === false) ? '?' : '&') . $u;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $u);
```

**Segestão 2:**
Utilizar o método POST e enviar a variável por esta via:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $u);
```

Creio que estas duas sugestões funcionará, pois ambas produzem uma requisição praticamente exclusiva.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rodrigo! deu certinho a sugestão 1.